# Modify Column / Range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For a cell **B1** with value **063**, I can use **`B1&_'txt'`** in a formula like this:

`sumif(A:A, B1&"_txt", Z:Z)`

Is there a way of do something similar to a column? like:

**`sumif(A:A&"_txt", B1, Z:Z)`**

Which in this case appends `_txt` to all values **without need for a helper column**

Comment: supposing that such a way exists, isn't 
sumif(A:A&"_txt", B1&"_txt", Z:Z)
equivalent to
sumif(A:A, B1, Z:Z)
??

Which begs the question, what does one want to achieve by modifying the column?

Comment: I removed the middle `_txt` to make this clearer. I get data from another source, 564 for example could be formatted as numbers and other times as strings, I'd like my formula to work without having to guess the type. I'm sure there are multiple ways to solve this, just looking if something similar to able is possible

Comment: alright, understood. If you are familiar with vba, such situations, where the format of the data can differ, can be dealt with quite elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula:

*Note array formulas need to be entered using* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Sift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SUM(IF(A:A&"_text"=B1,Z:Z,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than always adding the suffix `"_txt"` how about removing it from `B1`:

=SUMIF(A:A, LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-4),Z:Z)

Comment: Thanks but not in this particular case.

Comment: Why not? You'll have to give us more info